# What Happens when a Generator Runs out of Values to Yield?

Tags: python, generator, yield-keyword

To illustrate the question, suppose we have this simple generator:

```
def firstn(n):
    num = 0
    while num < n:
        yield num
        num += 1

for i in firstn(10):
    print i
```

This will print the digits 0 through 9. But what if we have:

```
def firstn(n):
    num = 0
    while num < 5 < n:
        yield num
        num += 1

for i in firstn(10):
    print i
```

(The change is in the `while` statement.) Then it prints only digits 0 through 4. Once `num >= 5`, then the generator no longer yields values.

What I'm curious about is what goes on under the hood: I used [PythonTutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display) to step through the code, and the impression I'm under is that once the `while` statement is no longer `True`, the function implicitly returns `None`, which the `for` loop somehow detects, and then also breaks. I used the `next` built-in to inspect this more closely:

```
>>> def firstn(n):
...     num = 0
...     while num < 5 < n:
...         yield num
...         num += 1
... 
>>> 
>>> mygen = firstn(100)
>>> next(mygen)
0
>>> next(mygen)
1
>>> next(mygen)
2
>>> next(mygen)
3
>>> next(mygen)
4
>>> next(mygen)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Which supports my theory. My big question: how does `StopIteration` work, and does this mean that calling a generator with a large value can be equivalent to calling it with its smallest terminating value? In our example, `for i in firstn(5)` and `for i in firstn(9999999999999)` should be equivalent, right?

Comment: You are aware that `num < 5 < n` just means `num < 5 and 5 < n`, right?

Comment: For the second case, yes. No matter what you pass in, as long as it's bigger than 5, it'll return 1..4. Once a generator runs out of values, it raises a `StopIteration` exception, which tells the caller that it ran out of data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't very mysterious. When a generator runs out of values to yield, it raises a `StopIteration` exception. You just need to understand how a for-loop works in Python. Essentially, it is equivalent to the following code:

```
iterator = iter(collection)
while True:
    try:
        x = next(iterator)
        # do something
    except StopIteration as e:
        break
```

The above is equivalent to:

```
for x in collection:
    # do something
```

Comment: Cool. I didn't know that a for loop used `StopIteration` to break. Thanks.

Comment: @Newb Don't be deceived, though, this is merely the equivalent Python. Under the hood, it is a much more optimal C implementation (in CPython).