# What happens if I do not yield anything to `yield from`?

Tags: python, yield, yield-from

What happens if I do not `yield` anything to `yield from`?

This is an example:

```py
def inner(x):
    if x > 0:
        yield "Greater than zero"
    elif x==0:
        yield "Zero"

def outer():
    yield from inner(x)
```

In this case `inner(x)` yields something to `outer()` if and only if x is >= 0.

What happens if x is negative?

Comment: Did you mean for `outer` to have an argument `x`? Why not try it yourself and see what happens?

Comment: Nothing happens with generators until you use them by calling `next`. In this case `next(inner(-1))` raises a `StopIteration` exception, which is what we expect when a generator has nothing more to say. You will get a `StopIteration` from `outer` as well. If you do something like `list(outer())` you will get an empty list as expected.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi it is not important where `x` comes from, anyway I asked while trying since I am new to `yield` keyword, so I am not sure what I am expecting

Comment: Related: [What Happens when a Generator Runs out of Values to Yield?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39110210/2745495)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same thing that happens if you use `inner(-1)` directly as an iterator; `yield from` simply passes along whatever was yielded. If it doesn't `yield` anything, the `StopIteration` exception is thrown, and this exception passes through. Operators or functions that loop over the iterator interpret this as the end of the sequence and stop iterating; if you don't call `outer()` from such a construct, you'll see the exception itself.